# Htmlunit - click() doesn't work

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am spidering a web page ... but click() doesnt work, or doesn't navigate ...
Any clue what could be the issue ? I'm using 2.25 version

you can see all details in the code, thank you very much in advance.

this my code:

```
@Test
public String xxx() throws Exception {

        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault())) {

            webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(15000);
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(30000);
            webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
            webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

            // add to log variable
            //toLog.append(" contrato: ").append(numeroContrato);

            final HtmlPage consultaCuentaPage = webClient.getPage(url);

            // grab first form
            final HtmlForm consultarCuentaForm = consultaCuentaPage.getForms().get(0);

            // numero cuenta input
            final HtmlInput numeroCuentaInput = consultarCuentaForm.getInputByName("nroCuenta");

            // consultar button
            final HtmlInput consultarButton = consultarCuentaForm.getInputByName("commandConsultar");

            // Change the value of the text field
            numeroCuentaInput.setValueAttribute("1111");


            // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
            final HtmlPage consultaCuentaPage2 = consultarButton.click();

            LOG.info("time: " + consultaCuentaPage2.getWebResponse().getLoadTime());
            //  LOG.info("time: " + consultaCuentaPage2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());

            //System.out.println(consultaCuentaPage2.asText());

            ////*[@id="form"]/div[1]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1] 
            if (consultaCuentaPage2.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"form\"]/div[1]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]") != null) {
                return ((HtmlTableDataCell)consultaCuentaPage2.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"form\"]/div[1]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).asText();
            }       
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: solved with this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551043/process-ajax-request-in-htmlunit